# IE6 only scrolls halfway down my page - how to diagnose?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I put together [a site](http://www.tazakigroup.com) that generally works well on FF, Chrome and IE8 (yes, I'm new to this):

I heard from our office in Japan who all use IE6 that various pages are not displaying properly, in short they stop scrolling when the page should scroll further - the scroll allowance is too short. I have [confirmed this for myself](http://www.tazakigroup.com/about-background_en.html).

Its not that I can't find a million suggestions for IE6 workarounds, but how to diagnose this problem? Is there a bug name for this?

A good diagnosis would be immensely appreciated - have spent hours on this now, to no avail, at tearing-out-hair stage.

Comment: People are *still* using IE6???

Comment: 2% in UK and surpisingly 6% in Japan - the unfortunate truth

Answer (score 0):

When you use 'float:xxx', browsers can not calculate the height/width of element properly, you have to use 'clear:both' an element that resides after floating box.

Don't forget that when you position the element absolutely, then other elements doesn't look at it while positioning themselves.

Example on jsfiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/tWJYJ/
```

In first example green and orange boxes doesn't see the red box while calculating positions, because it's positioned absolutely.